# Serialize all properties of class to XML

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a load of classes and I need to generate an XML schema for these classes.

The easiest way I can think to do this is to create the classes, serialize as XML and then run XSD on this XML.

However, if I don't set the properties of a class, no XML node is created and therefore the XSD doesn't pick it up.

Is there a way for me to tell the XML serializer to serialize ALL properties of a class, rather than just the ones that have values set?

Hopeful, more than expecting!
Duncan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSD.EXE can generate schemas from an assembly. Just specify the `/type` switch.

Comment: Thanks, as a reminder to everyone you need to give the fully qualified namespace, like so:

xsd Assembly.dll /type:namespace.* /outputdir:C:\temp

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and you have complete control.

Also, I am sure you already know there are a couple different ways to parse/validate Xml… and since you are on the Microsoft platform… these tools (available on MSDN) come in handy (auto generate C# code) if you decide to serialize/deserialize to/from a schema: xsd.exe and xsdObjectGen.exe (more options).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this.  I was also wondering if there was a magic attribute I could attach to my class which would do the above without me needing to implement this interface?

Answer (score 2):

Use metadata attribute

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]
```

It will, however, add extra attribute xsi:nil="true" to the serialized output, if the field is null.